# WCSession and Today Widget

Tags: ios, watchkit, ios8-today-widget, watchos-2, today-extension

I've an app with a today extension and a watch app. From the main app WCSession works fine and data is transferred to the watch and received correctly but when I try to send or receive data through the WCSession in the today widget the property `paired` and `watchAppInstalled` of the session are set to false so calling `transferUserInfo:` does nothing and `session:didReceiveUserInfo:` is never called.

I know I can open the app using `openURL` and then send the new data but I want to do that without leaving Notification Center.
Does anyone know a nice workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the watch app is running in the foreground, you should be able to send it a message via a Darwin notification. Take a look at [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: Let's say I have the today widget and the watch app open but not the app, if the watch send a direct message to the app with sendMessage: the app should be opened in the background allowing it to receive userInfo and notify the widget through the wormhole. Could this work?

Comment: I would use [openParentApplication:reply](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/openParentApplication:reply:) to notify the app. Then you could use MMWormhole to notify the today extension.

Comment: Since the app is targeted for watchOS 2 `openParentApplication:reply:` is not available but `sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:` method of WCSession does the same job. Do you have any idea on how to wake the app from notification center?

Comment: There is no way to directly wake the app from a today widget, except launching it with `openURL`

Answer (score 5):

It seems WCsession only works from the iOS app, not from any iOS extensions (share, today, keyboard, etc.), so for now you'll have to "relay" things via the app if you want to get it to the watch.

You should file an enhancement bug report with Apple explaining why you think it should be possible to use it from extensions too!

Comment: Done that, I'll post an update when I get a response

Comment: What's the radar number in case any perusing Apple engineers stop by?

Comment: They gave me #22434298

Comment: Update: my bug report has been marked as duplicate of #22302522 and will be closed