# share data between iOS 10 Widget and Apple Watch

Tags: swift, realm, ios10, mmwormhole

Let's say we have running widget on iPhone and app on Apple Watch at the same time. How to inform Apple Watch that we have made any changes to the model with widget?
App Groups are not longer supported by Apple Watch so we can't use MMWormhole nor Realm to share database...
Widget does not support Watch Connectivity and I end up with outdated model

How to handle this situation when the main app is closed?
iOS10, watchOS3, Swift 3

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

[MMWormhole apparently also supports the `WatchConnectivity` framework](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole#communication-with-watchconnectivity) of watchOS 2, so you should still be able to use it to send data.

Unfortunately, according to [this Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51600) thread (and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209138/wcsession-and-today-widget)), it is simply not possible to use `WatchConnectivity` from a Today extension. It will always be necessary to pass any data added by the Today Widget back up to the host app, and then have the host app pass the data to the watch.